# What steps do I need to take to use Drush Make on a Windows machine?

Tags: drush

[I have the Drush Windows installer.](http://drush.ws/drush_windows_installer) I download the Drush Make module and put it in the drush\commands folder. Still I don't have any luck with Drush Make on Windows.

Comment: Have you any error or message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the solution on this page.](http://drupal.org/node/1260084) There were several steps but it really wasn't that difficult. For some reason it doesn't download items from Github but that might be something to do with the path variable not being set correctly and I just downloaded a few modules from Github manually.